# How to display navigation links on an embedded photosphere?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

I took a photosphere and embedded it using the following code [(thanks to Dr.Molle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350973/how-to-embed-a-photosphere-in-a-website) :

```
<script>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere';
        new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
            position: {lat: 45.3189037,lng:5.605167},
            pov: {
              heading: -65,
              pitch: 5
            },
            zoom: 1
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="pano" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
```

Now I would like to add navigation links to other photospheres. I tried the ["links" property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomPanoramaMethod) with no success.

Comment: Is your `links` value an array for the [`StreetViewLink`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewLink) object? Can you provide us the values for it?